# Different results when using formula in Google Spreadsheet and Excel

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, formula

I am having trouble understanding the IF statement. What I am trying to do is:

1. In Excel I'm using this formula:

   `=IFERROR(IF(A1+1<=$B$1,A1+1,""),"")`

[image]

2. In Google Spreadsheet I'm using the same formula like above

   `=IFERROR(IF(A1+1<=$B$1,A1+1,""), "")`

[image]

But the results are different. How can I get the same result in Google Spreadsheet and in Excel?

Comment: 1. *'that is different'* is not an adequate error description. 2. Why would you require an IFERROR wrapper?

Comment: can i show you capture different result betweet excel and speadsheet, for more detail.

Comment: maybe let me be more clear, i send the capture excel and spreadsheet it. I tried to upload but failed, sorry because I just joined in this stack overflow. if I may ask your email so I can send the picture

Answer (score 4):

```
=IF(AND(A1+1<=$B$1,NOT(ISBLANK(A1))), A1+1,)
```

- This is for GoogleSheets to replicate the same result as Excel.
- Difference in results is because Sheets consider blanks as zero.